# Why not use 波長が合う

Tags: particle-と, particle-が

> 短い人生の中で
>
> 最も楽しいことは
>
> 自分の心の**波長と合う**人との
>
> 出会いです
>
> **稲盛和夫**

Why not use 「波長が合う人」, but 「波長と合う」?

Answer (score 4):

This is about the difference in the speaker's perspectives.  If you asked me, however, if the difference was huge (or very important), I would mostly have to reply negatively.

> 自分{じぶん}の心{こころ}の波長{はちょう}**が**合{あ}う人
>
> 自分の心の波長**と**合う人

The **former** is told from one's （自分） own viewpoint.

> "people that one/you get(s) along well with" or
>
> "people that one/you is/are on the same wavelength as"

The **latter** is told from the other people's （人） viewpoint.

> "people that get along well with one/you" or
>
> "people that are on the same wavelength as one/you

The "you" used in the above translations is the impersonal "you".

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Great! I got it now. You explained clearly. Merci, l’électeur 